# A weird directional derivative, escalar function composed with a real function

Tags: calculus, multivariable-calculus

Let $f:\mathbb{R}\to\mathbb{R}$ be a diferenciable function. Define $\Phi(x,t):=f(x-t)$. If $f'(0)=6$, calculate the directional derivative of $\Phi$ in the direction of the vector $v=(-19,0)$. (It's not necessary any point.)

Comment: It is said that the answer is -6, but why?

Answer (score 0):

$\partial_v\Phi(x,t)=\Phi'(x,t)v$. We have

$$\Phi'(x,t)=(\partial_xf(x-t)\quad \partial_tf(x-t))=(f'(x-t)\quad -f'(x-t))$$
Then the directional derivative is $\partial_v\Phi(x,t)=\Phi'(x,t)v=-19f'(x-t)$. For $x=t$, this is an explicit number, with the information you are given.